# Can you give me a sample code for this image

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have been trying to recreate a picture/design using just HTML and CSS but I keep getting stuck when it comes to the positioning.
[The image I'm trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAfSk.jpg)

Can someone give me tips on what to do?

This is my code for the CSS.
I know I messed up with the positioning but I don't have any other ideas

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap');
.main{
   width: 1440px;
    background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
.inner{
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: purple 50px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 20%;
    margin-top: 30%;
}
.texts{
    background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
    font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
    width: 47.5%;
    transform:translateY(60%);
    height: 40%;
}
.mainhead{
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}
.insights{
    color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}
.mainparagraph, .stats{
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
}
.stathead{
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
}
p {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.image{
    width:fit-content;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: hsl(277, 98%, 38%);
    transform: translate(90%, -40%);
}
img {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="main">
        <section class="inner">
            <section class="texts">
                <h1 class="mainhead">
                    Get <span class="insights">insights </span>that help your business grow.
                </h1>
                <p class="mainparagraph">
                    Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.
                </p>
                <section class="bottom">
                    <h1 class="stathead">10k+</h1>
                    <p class="stats">COMPANIES</p>
                </section>
                <section class="bottom">
                    <h1 class="stathead">314</h1>
                    <p class="stats">TEMPLATES</p>
                </section>
                <section class="bottom">
                    <h1 class="stathead">12M+</h1>
                    <p class="stats">QUERIES</p>
                </section>
            </section>
            <section class="image">
                <img src="images/image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="">
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Here's a start, i tried to keep the code to a minimum so you can understand it https://jsfiddle.net/dyj419na/ When building a UI you first break it apart like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXDI0.jpg it would make it easy for you to work with

Comment: thank you so much!!
I really appreciate it
but can you explain the whole flex concept to me?

Comment: or refer me to where I can read up about it

Comment: There's plenty of articles out there, a quick google search can get you started, But of course you start from the MDN which i think you'll be visiting a lot over the years https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine this snippet below. Positioning can be done by using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or CSS Grid. Here the former is used. I took the liberty to modify the HTML and CSS to such extend so that it (closely) matches your images.

I'd recommend that you read up on when you should use what HTML element, like a `<section>`. Look into Flexbox first, then check see [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), they will be important for creating layouts and make your life a lot easier if you get the hang of them.

The image is done with a combination of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter), an overlay and [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

**Be sure to check the links @zohirsalak posted about breaking apart the design in smaller chunks. It's a very good visualization and a good lesson to learn.**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap');

*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.insights {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.insights .texts {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.insights h1 {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.insights .highlight {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}

.insights p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
}

.insights .stats {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 4rem 0 0;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.insights .stats strong {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
}

.insights .stats span {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.insights .image {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.insights .image::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.insights .image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="insights">
  <div class="texts">
    <h1>Get <span class="highlight">insights </span>that help your business grow.
    </h1>
    
    <p>
      Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.
    </p>
    
    <ul class="stats">
      <li>
        <strong>10k+</strong>
        <span>Companies</span>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <strong>314</strong>
        <span>Templates</span>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <strong>12M+</strong>
        <span>Queries</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3184357/pexels-photo-3184357.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
  </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much
please can you explain the flex concept to me? or refer me to where I can know more about it

Comment: The link in the description of the answer leads to a CSS Tricks post which explains all Flexbox properties in detail. IMO it's the best article out there about Flexbox. But here it is again: [CSS Tricks: A guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)